# "How to Format" box is too Stack Overflow specific

Tags: feature-request

On a cooking stack exchange (or on any non-code stack exchange), these tips do **not** belong in the prominent "How to Format" box on the `/questions/ask` page:

- indent code by 4 spaces
- backtick escapes `like _so_`

Comment: For the record, the current "how to format" box *really* confused me before I realized it was a carryover from StackOverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Agreed. We probably do want people to know how to achieve this effect though. I'm not sure how to describe it to non-coders though.

Comment: Actually, we probably don't; it runs the risk of people accidentally triggering some wonky syntax highlighting.  Better for them to just use the regular quoting syntax (either `>` or `<pre>`).

Comment: @Aaronaught: there's a whole page explaining markdown, shouldn't the commonly used stuff be in that box?

Comment: @Dinah: Sure, but code formatting won't be commonly used on a cooking site, and assuming the site takes off, most people won't even understand what it means.  I think the feature should probably be turned off entirely (and in fact, I think there was another discussion about that somewhere...)